# Angular: How to access ActivatedRoute snapshot data from another component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the Angular2 [Material Toolbar](https://material.angular.io/components/component/toolbar) and I want to pass the current page title to it.

My **app.component** has a header component and the current page component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mi-root',
  template: `
     <mi-header></mi-header>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

In my **app.routing** I have a routing object with custom `title` property:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  }, {
    path: 'settings',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Settings'
    }
  }
];
```

Now I want to access the `data.title` property from my **header.component** but unfortunately it is undefined. My `data` object is empty:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'mi-header',
  template: `
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
      <span class="u-ml">{{title}}</span>
    </md-toolbar>
  `,
  styles: []
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.title = this.route.snapshot.data['title'];
  }
}
```

If I try to access the same property with the same way but from the `HomeComponent` or `SettingsComponent` it works fine:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'mi-settings',
  template: `
    <h1>Welcome to {{title}} screen</h1>
  `,
  styles: []
})

export class SettingsComponent {
  title: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.title = route.snapshot.data['title'];
  }
}
```

So, how can I access the `route.snapshot.data['title']` from my `HeaderComponent` ?

Comment: That's because `header.component` is not a *routed component*. There's no route associated to it, hence no `data`. Have you looked into *router events* (as described in [this blog post](https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```ts
  constructor(router:Router, route:ActivatedRoute) {
    router.events
    .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .forEach(e => {
      console.log('title', route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data.title);
    }
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xO08BfRD76GgRiiiaxat?p=preview)

Comment: For `router.firstChild` it returns me `null`. I know that I am doing something wrong. Can you give me an example, please :)

Comment: Then it's probably a leaf segment that doesn't have child routes. Try `router.root.firstChild`

Comment: Can you please create a Plunker to reproduce? Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 TS template.

Comment: yes, this is the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/rBToHRaukDlrSKcLGavh?p=preview